# Solving a Pde after reducing it to its Canonical Form

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The equation given is $$x^2u_{xx}-2xyu_{xy}-3y^2u_{yy}=0$$

$b^2-ac=4x^2y^2$ which is zero on the axes and positive everywhere else. So I look at places other than the axes. 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-xy\pm \sqrt{4x^2y^2}}{x^2}$$

Thus solving $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y}{x}$ gives me $\xi(x,y)=\dfrac{x}{y}$ and solving $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{-3y}{x}$ gives $\eta(x,y)=x^3y$.

Now reducing this system of $(x,y)$ in terms of $(\xi,\eta)$:
 $$u_x=\frac{u_{\xi}}{y}+3x^2y u_{\eta}$$
 $$u_y=\frac{-xu_{\xi}}{y^2}+x^3 u_{\eta}$$
$$u_{xx}=\frac{u_{\xi \xi}}{y^2}+6x^2u_{\xi \eta}+6xyu_{\eta}+9x^4y^2u_{\eta \eta}$$
$$u_{xy}=\frac{-u_{\xi}}{y^2}+\frac{-2x^3}{y}u_{\xi \eta}+3x^2u_{\eta}+3x^5yu_{\eta \eta}-\frac{x}{y^3}u_{\xi \xi}$$
$$u_{yy}=\frac{2xu_{\xi}}{y^3}+\frac{-2x^4}{y^2}u_{\xi \eta}+\frac{x^2}{y^4}u_{\xi \xi}+x^6{u_{\eta \eta}}$$

Putting these in the original equation yields $15\xi \eta u_{\xi \eta}-4\xi u_{\xi}=0$.The initial conditions are given as: $u(x,1)=\phi(x)$ and $u_{y}(x,1)=\psi(x)$, where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are smooth functions. I need to first find a general solution and then a particular solution.

Arranging the above equation yields this: $$\frac{u_{\xi \eta}}{u_{\xi}}=\frac{4}{15\eta}$$
Integrating this with respect to $\eta$ gives $$\ln u_{\xi}=\ln {\eta}^{\frac{4}{15}} + \ln g(\xi)$$
 Again integrating the above equation w.r.t $\xi$ gives $$u(\xi,\eta)=\int g(\xi){\eta}^{\frac{4}{15}} d \xi + f(\eta)$$

How do I put in the initial conditions??

Thanks for the help!!