Jacobian is zero when checking for valid answers for second order linear PDE, how to proceed?
I have the following PDE: $x^{2}u_{xx}-2xyu_{xy}-3y^{2}u_{yy}+u_{y}=0$ checking the discriminant I get that $$\Delta=\left(-2xy\right)^{2}-4\cdot x^{2}\cdot\left(-3y^{2}\right)=4x^{2}y^{2}+12x^{2}y^{2}=16x^{2}y^{2}=\left(4xy\right)^{2}\geq0$$
this only holds when $x\ne0\lor y\ne0$ so outside those cases I should get the canonical form of hyperbola, meaning $u_{qq}-u_{rr}=f\left(q,r,u_{q},u_{r}\right)$.
solving the characteristic ODE I get:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy\pm4xy}{2x^{2}}=\frac{y\pm2y}{x}\Rightarrow\frac{dy}{y\pm2y}=\frac{dx}{x}\stackrel{\intop}{\Rightarrow}\ln\left|y\pm2y\right|-\ln\left|x\right|=\ln c\Rightarrow\frac{y\pm2y}{x}=c$$
so I got my two solutions for the coordinates change meaning:
$$\begin{cases}
q=\frac{3y}{x}\\
r=-\frac{y}{x}
\end{cases}$$
now we can see they're not linearly independent, hence the Jacobian is $0$ and we learned that the Jacobian can't be zero, but I can't figure out what I've done wrong.
looking for help understanding what has gone wrong with this method specifically, this is the way we learned, so I want to stay consistent.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430371/solving-a-pde-after-reducing-it-to-its-canonical-form?noredirect=1.

@Gonçalo thanks!

@Nate3384 The last term $u_y$ makes the problem difficult.
Without this term one can transform with $\left{q\to\frac{x}{y},r\to x^3 y\right}$
and finally find $$u_q=4r\cdot u_{qr}$$
